# Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Kernel

Tags: kernel, 22.04

Yesterday I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and when upgrading my kernel is still at the same version as before, at version 5.15, does anyone know how I can upgrade the kernel?

Here is the output of the command: `uname -rs`

```
Linux 5.15.0-73-generic
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Kernel 5.15.0-73-generic** is the default kernel on 22.04 at this point. The reason why it has remained the same is because you had the **hwe** kernel installed on your 20.04 release instead of the default one.

What you can do on 22.04 is install the **hwe** kernel again so that you can use **kernel 5.19.0-43** at this point.

`sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04`

The new installation **will not** remove the current kernel. In case of problems with the new kernel, which is highly unlikely, you can always use the **grub boot menu** and tell the system to use the current kernel instead of the newly installed one.

On this link: [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time) you will find instructions on how to activate this menu.

If this happens though, you have to remove the hwe kernel afterwards so that you don't have to select through the **grub boot menu** the older kernel every time you start your system.

`sudo apt purge linux-generic-hwe-22.04`

**Personal recommendation:**
If your system is running well with kernel **5.15.0-73-generic**, I would recommend you keep using it instead of updating it. The hwe kernel is exactly what it says. It's a Hardware Enablement kernel that doesn't have to be used if the system is running OK. The default kernel is receiving all the necessary updates regularly and you don't have to worry about installing a later kernel manually.

Comment: What is the possibility that I run this command and give something wrong? I'm afraid of updating and my computer won't turn on afterward. I'm a beginner in the world of Linux, so I don't understand much about it.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: I just updated, installed it the way you said, running the command: sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04, after that I restarted the computer and my kernel is already updated. Now it's in this version: Linux 5.19.0-43-generic. The reason for the update is because I am facing a problem with the previous kernel, in this case the 5.15 kernel, my computer was not shutting down correctly, it was turning off only the monitor screen, but the monitor light was always on.

Comment: I was told to update the kernel which will solve this problem, so I hope it really does, I'll use the computer for a few days and see if it solves it, thank you very much for helping to update the kernel!